# ¿Por qué se llena mi disco duro cuando hago un select a mi tabla y como evitarlo en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, almacenamiento

Tengo una tabla, esta tabla tiene como unos 13 campos. Tengo varios registros en mi tabla, aunque no llega ser demasiado solo unos 3 millones aproximadamente. Mi tabla cuenta con varios índices en distintos campos, pero el único índice clustered es el del id que es un entero auto-incrementable. Cuando hago un select a la tabla veo que a medida que la data va cargando el disco C (de mi pc local) se va llenando poco a poco con el correr de los segundos hasta que se llena completamente y la data deja de cargar, así que detengo la ejecución y al cabo de un rato el disco regresa a la normalidad. No entiendo porque pasa esto ya que mi bd esta en otro disco en un servidor aparte. Alguna ayuda o explicación.

Nota: Mi tabla tiene 13 campos su id es entero autoincrementable, uno de sus campos es de tipo de archivo varbinary(max) y puede ser nulo, pero en varios registros no lo es. Otro dato aunque nose si sea importante decir es que la tabla esta particionada en dos particiones.

Comment: Ya se que me podrían decir que libere espacio en mi disco y ya, pero creo que esa no seria la solución más optima.

Comment: Una select no puede escribir en tu disco local nunca. Solo ante la ausencia de memoria para recoger los datos que te envía el servidor utilizará el archivo de paginación, emulando a la RAM que necesita. El hecho de que tenga un tipo de índice u otro tampoco es importante, porque eso solo le sirve al servidor para montar la salida de la consulta. El problema es que no tienes memoria RAM libre, para contener esta consulta, y tu sistema está usando el archivo de paginación.

Comment: @Javifer2 y como se aproximadamente cuanto de RAM consumirá mi consulta.  porque en la pc que lo probé tenia 9GB de RAM en total pero no me fije cuanta memoria libre tenia en ese momento. Hay algún método para saber cuanta memoria necesito. Lo que si me fije es q mientras mas espacio libre tenia el disco pues cargaba mas data. La ultima ves que probé mi disco tenia como 30 GB libres de 70 aprox.

Comment: Son cosas diferentes. Tu archivo de paginación debería de tener un limite. Por encima de ese limite, no crece. Suele ser buena práctica de 2 a 2,5 veces el tamaño de la RAM. pero eso es una opinión. Puedes buscar en google, sin esfuerzo como configurar el archivo de paginación. Por otro lado. La data mide lo que mida en función del tipo de dato y de la cantidad que tiene. El id 4 bytes por nº de filas. El resto en función del tipo de datos y de su contenido. Si contienen textos pueden ser gigantescos. Adiciona a la pregunta como es la tabla y se calcula aprox. Tipo de dato y nº de filas.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que su consulta está haciendo uso de spool o está haciendo "spilling" (una forma de implementar memoria virtual) a TEMPDB. Sin embargo, si fuera TEMPDB el tamaño del archivo en disco no disminuira automáticamente; lo que hace sospechar de paginación del buffer pool por parte de windows.

Revise el plan de su consulta. Agregue indices para evitar usar hash joins u otros operadores que puedan requerir mucha memoria.